# What is the best way to check whether lead belongs to Queue or User?

Tags: apex, trigger, user, queue

I'm trying to determine in a trigger, whether a lead belongs to a Queue or a User. What is the best way of going about this?

I tried the method mentioned in a dev. force discussion:

```
System.debug( lead.Owner.type )
```

... but this consistently keeps fetching null.

Alternatively, I was trying to determine by first 3 characters of the OwnerId (005 for User, 00G for Queue). I tried using:

```
lead.OwnerId.substring( 3 ) == '005'
```

Trying the above gets me **Method does not exist or incorrect signature**.

Any bright ideas here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is to not rely on the key prefix. Instead, just ask salesforce what the type is:

```
if(lead.OwnerId != null) { // User is currently known
    if(lead.OwnerId.getSObjectType() == User.SObjectType) {
        // Owner is a user
    } else if(lead.OwnerId.getSobjectType() == Group.SObjectType) {
        // Owner is a group
    }
}
```

To use Owner.Type, you need a query first:

```
Lead[] records = [SELECT Owner.Type FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];
```

Note: Owner ID isn't always available in trigger context (e.g. Before Insert), because the owner isn't assigned until later.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get the error **Method does not exist or incorrect signature** is due to `Substring` being a method of the String class. You need to cast the owner id into a string and then check.

Have a look at the string methods [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

On the documentation, there are also examples of how to convert other data types into strings or assign the id to a string variable. You also need to specify the `startIndex` and the `endIndex` in the `Substring` method, information that is available in the link I've provided.

Comment: Thank you Mihai. I had a feeling it was due to type casting errors. However, checking for the first 3 characters seems like a hackish solution.  Lead.Owner.type would have been more elegant - any idea why it returns null?

Comment: Lead owner is a polymorphic field and hence needs to be accessed differently. For more details read http://mightycoder.blogspot.com/2013/06/sneak-peak-salesforce-polymorphic-keys.html

Comment: I was focusing more on your error, rather than providing an alternative. I think sfdcfox's answer is what you are looking for. At least you've learned why it threw the error.