# What is API name of 'Location' field in hierarchy custom setting or how to get it in code?

Tags: apex, soql, customsetting

I want to fetch type of hierarchy setting(profile OR User), compare it and do some logic. For that I am using setupOwner.Type in SOQL query as:

```
SELECT SetupOwner.Name,SetupOwner.Type,SetupOwnerId, Field1__c,
            FROM MyUserSettings__c
            ORDER BY SetupOwner.Name
```

It is giving me output as:

```
> SetupOwner.Type for User: 'User'
> SetupOwner.Type for profile: '00e'
> SetupOwner.Type for org: '00D'
```

But when I use where clause:

```
 where SetupOwner.Type='00e'
```

it gives me 0 results.

How can we obtain records where type is 'Profile'? Or what is the API name of field 'Location' in hierarchy settings?

Also, I could not find official documentation for 'SetupOwner'. Is there any?

Comment: @Reshma : Yes, but it does not have ans required by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a custom setting feature, you are referring to a polymorphic field, refer [Cross-Object Owner Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/cross-object-owner-fields-a-powerful-new-formula-option.html).

Now you can add filter after querying:

```
for(OverrideStandardButtons__c setting: [SELECT Name, 
    SetupOwnerId FROM OverrideStandardButtons__c]) {
    if(setting.SetupOwnerId.getSObjectType() == User.SObjectType ||
        setting.SetupOwnerId.getSObjectType() == Profile.SObjectType) {
        System.debug('ownerType: ' + setting.Name);
    }
}
```

Credit goes to [sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72817/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-whether-lead-belongs-to-queue-or-user)!

---

**Added**-

For your example, simpler would be to use following query:

> SELECT Name, 
>       SetupOwnerId, SystemModstamp FROM OverrideStandardButtons__c
>       WHERE SetupOwnerId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Organization)

Comment: Thanks for the query and  answer, I need to study cross-object Owner fields. I modified your query to:

`SELECT SetupOwner.Name , SetupOwnerId FROM OverrideStandardButtons__c WHERE SetupOwnerId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Organization)`

Because I wanted name of the Profile/User, but for profile name, it is showing me **8** instead of **Standard Platform User**. Can you please calrify this as well?

Comment: You cannot retrieve the field directly, you have to use [`typeof`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) to retrieve data from polymorphic relationship!