# How to retrieve Profile name using typeof clause in SOQL for getting Hierarchy(User) type of custom settings

Tags: apex, soql, customsetting, polymorphism

I want to retrieve name of Profile for which a hierarchy type of custom setting is defined. This custom setting is not organisation wide default, but is specific for a profile. I got to know recently [in this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157275/what-is-api-name-of-location-field-in-hierarchy-custom-setting-or-how-to-get-i) that 'Location' field of custom setting is a polymorphic field and can't be accessed directly, but needs [TYPEOF clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm).

I have used following query to access the profile name but it is returning me a code(prefix ID probably) of that profile rather than name:

```
SELECT setupOwner.Name, customField1__c, customfield2__c 
    FROM myUserSetting__c WHERE 
    SetupOwnerId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Organization)
```

Then I tried using following query:

```
SELECT TYPEOF What
    WHEN myUserSetting__c THEN setupOwner.Name,
    ELSE customField1__c, customfield2__c 
    FROM myUserSetting__c 
    WHERE SetupOwnerId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Organization)
```

But it is giving me syntax error. Not able to understand the typeof syntax and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my custom setting, I have following:

[image]

And to retrieve only profile names from custom setting, you may use as following code having a polymorphic query:

```
for(OverrideStandardButtons__c setting: [SELECT 
        TYPEOF SetupOwner
            WHEN Profile THEN Id, Name, UserType
        END
    FROM OverrideStandardButtons__c WHERE 
    SetupOwnerId IN (SELECT Id FROM Profile)]) {
    // fetch the profile defination
    Profile objProfile = setting.SetupOwner;

    System.debug(objProfile + '----' + objProfile.Name);
}
```

Result of code:

> Profile:{Id=00e6F000002QmfaQAC, Name=System Administrator, UserType=Standard}----System Administrator
>
> Profile:{Id=00e6F000002QmfcQAC, Name=Analytics Cloud Integration User, UserType=Standard}----Analytics Cloud Integration User

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the answer,. Additionally, to get the User name and other fields of custom setting(custom fields) I would sum the query to :   
 `SELECT 
        TYPEOF SetupOwner
            WHEN Profile THEN Id, Name, UserType
            WHEN User THEN Name                          //gives username
        END,
       customField1__c, customField2__c, customField3__c
    FROM OverrideStandardButtons__c WHERE 
    SetupOwnerId IN (SELECT Id FROM Profile)`

Comment: You are welcome, glad to be of any help!

Answer (score 0):

In a polymorphic relationship, the referenced object of the relationship can be one of several objects.

The `What` relationship field of an Event could be an Account, a Campaign, or an Opportunity. When making queries or updating records with polymorphic relationships, you need to check the actual object type set for the relationship, and act accordingly.

For e.g.

```
SELECT 
  TYPEOF What
    WHEN Account THEN Name, Phone
    WHEN Opportunity THEN Amount, CloseDate
    ELSE Name, Email
  END
FROM Event
```

For more detail refer [Polymorphic Keys and Relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys)

Comment: Giving me error still: **No such relation 'What' on entity 'myUserSetting__C '. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.** Does it not work for custom settings?